# Windows: Open 3rd-party terminal via Explorer address bar in the current location?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I've been wondering about this simple question for quite some time. I know it can be done but I haven't succeeded in my Registry search. (I have `Git for Windows` installed and it's integrated just like the Command Prompt or PowerShell, so I've been searching for it to see how it's done, but all I managed to find was the right-click menu integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally any 3-rd party terminal after being added to the PATH variable opens in the current location just like the native CMD.

PS The author of this question was using ConEmu from PortableApps.com which for some reason didn't do that. And there's no problem with ConEmu from www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html

Comment: So you can type `ConEmu` in the address bar and this opens ConEmu at current path?

Comment: OK, I got it! I didn't know than any program in the PATH could be run this way from the Explorer and get current path as a parameter. This works great with Cmder + WSL too.